# How does `SIGWINCH` pass through Bash?

Tags: linux, bash, signals, tty, pty

If I run a program in Bash that listens for `SIGWINCH`, and I resize the terminal that Bash is running in, then the program will receive `SIGWINCH`. I would like to know how this signal gets relayed to the program running under Bash.

Here is my understanding of what happens, using a sample `catch_sig` program that I list at the end of this post:

- The terminal emulator will run Bash behind the receiving end of a PTY. Thus, the "STDIN" and "STDOUT" of Bash will be TTYs.
- Bash runs `catch_sig` as a sub-process by forking. The `catch_sig` process inherits Bash's FDs for I/O, which are the TTYs mentioned above.
- When the size of the terminal emulator changes it should call `ioctl(pty_fd, TIOCSWINSZ, &size)`, where `pty_fd` is the sending end of the above PTY. This call to `ioctl` will update the size of the receiving TTY and will attempt to send `SIGWINCH` the process group for the TTY.
- Bash and `catch_sig` are part of the above process group, so `SIGWINCH` gets sent to both of them individually.

One difficulty I'm having with the above however, is that if I attempt to send `SIGWINCH` to the process group for Bash manually with `kill` then `catch_sig` doesn't receive the signal. For example, if the PID (and process group) for Bash is `123` and I run `catch_sig` in it, and then I run `kill -WINCH -123` in a separate pane, then `catch_sig` doesn't receive the signal. Why is this this the case?

The following is source code for a demonstrative `catch_sig` program, as mentioned above:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static void sigwinch_handler(int sig) {
        printf("got signal: %d\n", sig);
}

int main() {
        signal(SIGWINCH, sigwinch_handler);
        printf("waiting for signal...\n");
        pause();
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> For example, if the PID (and process group) for Bash is `123` and I run `catch_sig` in it, and then I run `kill -WINCH -123` in a separate pane, then `catch_sig` doesn't receive the signal. Why is this this the case?

The terminal sends `SIGWINCH` to the foreground (i.e controlling) process group only. When Bash is [interactive](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/What-is-an-Interactive-Shell_003f.html#What-is-an-Interactive-Shell_003f), each job —foreground or background— is placed in a separate process group, and foreground jobs are temporarily given control of the terminal. For example:

<sub>Terminal #1:</sub>

```
$ tty
/dev/pts/0
$ echo $$
123
$ ./catch_sig
waiting for signal...
```

<sub>Terminal #2:</sub>

```
$ ps -t /dev/pts/0 -o pid,pgid,stat,comm
  PID  PGID STAT COMMAND
  123   123 S<s  bash
  124   124 S<+  catch_sig
```

The plus sign (`+`) in the `STAT` field means that the process is a member of the foreground process group, see [ps(1)](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html#PROCESS_STATE_CODES).

So, when you resize the terminal window while `catch_sig` is running in the foreground (i.e. its process group was made the foreground process group by Bash, and it hasn't completed yet), `SIGWINCH` is sent to `catch_sig`'s process group only. Then Bash reattains the control of the terminal as `catch_sig` terminates.

Which can be reproduced using `kill` as shown below.

<sub>Terminal #2:</sub>

```
$ kill -WINCH -124
```

<sub>Terminal #1:</sub>

```
got signal: 28
```

For further information, see [how job control is implemented in POSIX shells](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/xrat/V4_xbd_chap03.html#tag_21_03_00_36).